# How to loop back to beginning of program

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, actionlistener

I am trying to create a while loop with this condition. (a > 1) So basically. every time a is set to greater than 1, it will close the JFrame I created and then start the program over. My problem is that, when I try edit the integer "a" from within an action listener, it doesn't recognize that it has already been declared. This is somewhat difficult to actually describe, so here is my code.

```
    public class TestBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2;
            while(a > 1){
                a = 0;
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Box");
                frame.setSize(1200, 800);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6, 1, 1));
                JPanel panelAOne = new JPanel();
                JPanel panelATwo = new JPanel();
                JPanel emptySpace = new JPanel();
                JLabel labelAOne = new JLabel();
                labelAOne.setFont(new Font("Aerial", Font.ITALIC, 21));
                labelAOne.setText("Welcome to the Test Box!");
                JLabel labelATwo = new JLabel();
                labelATwo.setFont(new Font("Aerial", Font.ITALIC, 21));
                labelATwo.setText("Where would you like to go?");
                JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("stuff goes here");
                JButton buttonAOne = new JButton("Colors");
                panelAOne.add(labelAOne);
                panelAOne.add(labelATwo);
                panelATwo.add(buttonAOne);
                emptySpace.add(emptyLabel);
                frame.add(panelAOne);
                frame.add(buttonAOne);
                frame.add(emptySpace);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                buttonAOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        a = 2;
                //If this code is left as is, a GUI will open endlessly until it crashes the computer
            }
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: Define a as a field instead of a variable.  That is, move the declaration up above the main() definition.

Answer (score 3):

You look to be trying to shoe-horn a linear console program into a Swing event-driven GUI program or visa versa, and you really don't want to do that, and I would recommend that you re-structure your program. Instead, show your GUI, get the input, and re-request the input in the GUI if it's wrong. Don't use a console-type program while loop for this.

So, for instance if the ActionListener finds that the input is not valid, clear the text in the JTextField by calling `setText("")` on the JTextField, show the user a JOptionPane informing them of the error in input and await another press of the button. But leave the JFrame displayed.

Edit: I don't even see a JTextField in your code, so I'm not sure where the user is supposed to enter input.

Answer (score 3):

Your scheme cannot work, at least not reliably.  At the end of the first iteration of your loop, local variable `a` still has the value set at the top of the loop (`0`), so the loop exits and the application's main thread dies.  The GUI will continue to run, as it does so in a separate thread (the AWT's event-dispatch thread (EDT)), but even if you re-wrote your code so that an analog of variable `a` could be modified by your `ActionListener`, nobody who cares would still be paying attention by that point.  (Probably.  You have multiple threads sharing data without any synchronization, so really the behavior of your program is not well defined.)

GUI programming is fundamentally different from console programming, as Hovercraft Full Of Eels pointed out.  It requires a significant mental adjustment to move from one to the other, but the basic paradigm of GUI programming is that everything your program does is a response to an event.  Thus, if you want some sort of re-spawning behavior then you should obtain it by registering a listener for the appropriate event, and having it perform the work you want.